# What is the best way to automate Windows at a high level?

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey

I have been using AHK for a while, but since it is mainly for hotkeys I am wondering if there is something more powerful out there.

Comment: This isn't a particularly appropriate question for SuperUser as there will not be any 'clear' winner. If you could rephrase this by asking how to automate certain tasks (given you can figure it out) or things that can be given clear answers, that would be ideal. My general recommendation would be to take a look at Powershell or Python

Comment: @Abraxas Thanks for the downvote, but I was asking for a suggestion not a debate.  cml recommending Autolt was right on target.

Comment: Um dude, didn't downvote you. https://imgur.com/MXre9hj Also, that 2 next to my comment meant two people agreed. AutoIT has tons of tie ins with powershell.

Comment: @Abraxas Oh...figured it was you...my bad to assume.  Thanks for the suggestions, those will be good to try as I need to get in deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is a scripting language for automating Windows. I haven't used it in a while, but I remember it being very concise for doing some complex operations.